# Screen is not moving above the keyboard while entering text in fragment

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard

I have already with `adjustresize` and `adjustpan` also but nothing worked for me here.

Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/gray"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="9">
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/backgroiund"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="500dp"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="65dp">

                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_height="120dp">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:text="Srinivas"
                            android:id="@+id/user_name"
                            android:textSize="25sp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:text="Android Developer"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:text="Tadepalligudem,West Godavari"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/boarder"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:text="about"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:background="#dfdfdf"/>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:text="Intrests"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:background="#A9A9A9"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/bg1"
                                android:layout_weight="8.5">
                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/editsearch"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:layout_height="18dp"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:foregroundGravity="center"
                                    android:src="@drawable/search" />
                                <EditText
                                    android:id="@+id/name"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_weight="9"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                                    android:backgroundTint="#00000000"
                                    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                                    android:hint="Search Intrests"
                                    android:singleLine="true"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:background="@null"
                                    android:padding="2dp"
                                    android:textColorHint="#9B9B9B"/>
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:id="@+id/buton_layout"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="70dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/boarder">

                                <ScrollView
                                    android:id="@+id/scroll"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                                    <com.buzzed.utils.FlowLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                        android:id="@+id/flow_container1"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                        android:gravity="center"
                                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                                        app:elementSpacing="5dp"
                                        app:flowDirection="leftToRight"
                                        app:lineSpacing="14dp" />
                                </ScrollView>

                            </LinearLayout>
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_height="80dp"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent">

                                <Button
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:background="@drawable/circlecorner1"
                                    android:text="save"
                                    android:textSize="18sp"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                    android:id="@+id/save"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                                    android:onClick="save"
                                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                                    android:textColor="@color/White"
                                    android:layout_height="40dp" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                        </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:id="@+id/list_layout"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">
                            <ListView
                                android:id="@+id/listview"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/user_pic"
                    android:layout_width="140dp"
                    android:layout_height="140dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/grey_round"
                    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I used `AdjustPan` nothing happened but when I tried with `AdjustResize` the screen is scrollable and I can move it manually but what I need is to move screen automatically when keyboard open and yes it is happening in fragment. Please help me .

Comment: when your parent view group is scrollview, adjust pan and adjust nothing will not works. You should add some dummy layout with keypad height.